# post hoc test for linear mixed model with two variables

Tags: r, linear-programming, lme4, mixed-models, posthoc

I built a linear mixed model and did a *post hoc* test for it. Fixed factors are the phase numbers (time) and the group.

```
statistic_of_comp <- function (x, df) {
x.full.1 <- lmer(x ~  phase_num + group + (1|mouse), data=df, REML = FALSE)
x_phase.null.1 <- lmer(x ~ group + (1|mouse), data=df, REML = FALSE)
print(anova (x.full.1, x_phase.null.1))
summary(glht(x.full.1, linfct=mcp(phase_num="Tukey")))
}
```

Now my problem is, that I want to do a post hoc test with more than one fixed factor. I found the following

```
linfct=mcp(phase_num="Tukey", group="Tukey)
```

but that doesn't give the result I want. At the moment I get the comparison for the groups with Tukey (every group with every other group) and the comparison between the two phases.

What I want is a comparison of the phase_numbers for every group. 
e.g. group1 phase1-phase2 ..., group2 phase1-phase2 etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you can do this with `multcomp`, but let me illustrate how to do it with the `emmeans` package. I'm going to use a regular linear model (since you haven't given a reproducible example), but the recipe below *should* work just as well with a mixed model.

Linear model from `?emmeans` (using a built-in data set):

```
warp.lm <- lm(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
```

Apply `emmeans()`, followed by the `pairs()` function:

```
pairs(emmeans(warp.lm , ~tension|wool))
wool = A:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 L - M      20.556 5.16 48  3.986  0.0007 
 L - H      20.000 5.16 48  3.878  0.0009 
 M - H      -0.556 5.16 48 -0.108  0.9936 

wool = B:
 contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 L - M      -0.556 5.16 48 -0.108  0.9936 
 L - H       9.444 5.16 48  1.831  0.1704 
 M - H      10.000 5.16 48  1.939  0.1389
```

For more information, see `?pairs.emmGrid` or  `vignette("comparisons",package="emmeans")` (which clarifies that these tests do indeed use Tukey comparisons by default).

Comment: Unfortunately I have to say that I tried it with the linear mixed model and somehow it doesn't work. So in itself R executes the function, but I have the same p-value for all group comparisons, so I guess this is not correct.

Comment: can you give us a **reproducible** example to work with please ... ?